# Plotly JS Bar text font has gray outline

Tags: javascript, fonts, plotly, plotly.js

When I plot the following Plotly JS Bar chart, the color of the text in bars should be completely black but instead it looks like the border of the font is in gray and the inside is in black. I couldn't find anything in the doc to influence this. Anyone knows how to solve this ?

```js
var trace1 = {
    name: 'Protein Unit',
    x: ['2-167','2-75','2-138','2-241','77-138','77-167','139-167','139-241','168-241','168-205','168-341','206-241','242-341',],
    y: [2,3,2,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,1,1,7,],
    text: ['166','74','137','240','62','91','29','103','74','38','174','36','100',],
    textfont:{
        family: 'sans-serif, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont',
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        },
    font: {
        family: 'sans-serif, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont',
        size: 14,
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
    },
    textposition: 'auto',
    marker: {
        color: ['rgba(6, 150, 104, 1)', 'rgba(209, 41, 180, 1)', 'rgba(81, 243, 16, 1)', 'rgba(190, 107, 124, 1)', 'rgba(150, 218, 49, 1)', 'rgba(255, 42, 13, 1)', 'rgba(128, 80, 199, 1)', 'rgba(53, 200, 239, 1)', 'rgba(234, 70, 109, 1)', 'rgba(157, 28, 244, 1)', 'rgba(205, 219, 155, 1)', 'rgba(250, 209, 57, 1)', 'rgba(100, 221, 150, 1)', ],
        line: {
        color:  "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
        width: 0.5
        }
    },
    opacity: 0.7,
    type: "bar",
};
var data = [trace1];
var layout = {
    font: {
            family: 'IBM Plex Sans, sans-serif, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont',
            size:   17
    },
    bargap: 0.02,
    bargroupgap: 0.2,
    barmode: 'stack',
    margin: {
        b: 100,
        autoexpand: true
    },
    title: "Boundaries",
    xaxis: {title: "PU",
            type: 'category',
            tickangle: '35'},
    yaxis: {title: "Count",
            dtick: 1
            },
};
var config = {responsive: true};
Plotly.newPlot('pus_hist', data, layout, config);
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I found an "easy fast fix" but I didn't find the origin of the issue.
For some reason, the CSS generated for that text adds a colored stroke:

```css
g.point {
    fill: #2f225d;
    stroke: #afa2dc;
}
```

What I did is add in my custom css stylesheet:

```css
g.point {
    fill: #2f225d;
    stroke: None;
}
```

It solved the issue, yet didn't fix the "origin", if somebody knows anyway, always happy to hear !

**FIXED**

The problem was coming from another javascript library that I was importing beside the classical ones:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/calipho-sib/feature-viewer@v1.1.0/dist/feature-viewer.bundle.js"></script>
```

which is modifying the CSS class adding a stroke to the font.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something, I can't seem to reproduce your issue. See my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/merillium/pen/poWLebR). Does your html or css differ from mine?

Comment: Thank you so much for the codepen, I was able to simply paste all the JS imports I had and I figured out which one was in conflict: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/calipho-sib/feature-viewer@v1.1.0/dist/feature-viewer.bundle.js"></script>` (a viewer I use on the page next to the plot).